# Google spreadsheet gviz query is concatenating first two rows into header

Tags: csv, export, spreadsheet

I'm trying to get my Google spreadsheet to export correctly to CSV or HTML, selecting columns A and D. However, when I do this, it's concatenating the first rows into a single header. Here is the code:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aPYE6_umcG5I_3saNdkoBdPTilWtJOBJuzZDhOuZB0o/gviz/tq?tq=select%20A%2CD&tqx=out:html

It's not giving me what I want.

The first row should read, "Date" and "Cumulative Return".

The second row should read "date" and "number".

Then the following rows should be numbers.

Instead, it's concatenating the first two rows into a single header.

I need it in a particular format to import into Visualizer, a Wordpress plugin that does charts.

It's correct if I export the entire public sheet as html or csv, like with the following:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aPYE6_umcG5I_3saNdkoBdPTilWtJOBJuzZDhOuZB0o/pubhtml

But I need to select only columns A and D and export it correctly to CSV as that is what the Visualizer plugin requires.

How do I get it to do the correct output?

Comment: I did find a workaround this issue. I created an additional google sheet and dynamically copied over the columns I wanted using the ! cell directives. I then exported the full CSV from this specific sheet using the sheet ID without having to use the gviz query

Comment: I am having the same issue. The cause appears to be decimals as cell values. all cells in the row up to the first occurrence of a decimal are copied to the header. Here is a minimal example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F623EMFiwAsKDOeLlKDAS_xYI2jIobPLPv-_JGzH9tY/edit#gid=0 -- for sheets with one tab the workaround of using the simpler `/export` URLs works, but this is suboptimal for multi-tab sheets since an opaque ID must be passed for the tab.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem with the gviz-export links
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={sheet_name}](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%7Bkey%7D/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=%7Bsheet_name%7D)

Not only do they seem to concatenate empty rows, but it also removes some cell content (for example in my case "RGB(1,0,0)" format string were are removed).

Fortunately I found there's a simpler alternative URL format:
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/export?format=csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%7Bkey%7D/export?format=csv)

It doesn't give you all the flexibility of the gviz api, but it seems to return a csv with all the rows and cells unmodified.

If anyone out there knows how to get a similar unmodified output with the gviz api that would be great to hear about, but I haven't been able to that it anywhere.